# Javascript - Replace callback with function, including parameters

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, parameter-passing, referenceerror

Though Stackexchange Meta forbids me to start with "Hi,", I think there is no substantial harm to being friendly.

Hi,

I use the following piece of code,

```
while (!success) {
    new Magister(chosenSchool, username, password).ready(function(error){
        /* Code here using the error variable above */
    });
}
```

but JSLint warnes me that it would be a bad practice to define functions inside a loop.
However, using the following code, doesn't work either.

```
function checkLogin(error) {
    /* Code here using the error variable above */
}
while (!success) {
    new Magister(chosenSchool, username, password).ready(checkLogin(error));
}
```

This results into `Uncaught ReferenceError: error is not defined`. How can I not redefine a function, but still passing the `error` as in the original `function(error){...}`?
I tried various methods, but it won't budge for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `while (!success)` sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: @Bergi Oh I won't actually use that I think, I'll just fire a warning once and cancel the action and wait for a new call started by the user.. But still, I'd like to know the answer to my question :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't call the function:

```
new Magister(chosenSchool, username, password).ready(checkLogin);
```

`ready` expects a function object, so you have to pass `chechLogin` itself instead of calling it and passing its return value (which is likely `undefined`).

> How can I not redefine a function, but still passing the `error` as in the original `function(error){...}` ?

Maybe that's where the confusion lies. You are actually not passing `error` at all. The argument is passed by the **caller**, which is `ready`.

---

One nice feature of JavaScript is that you can simple replace variables with the literal representation of their value (in most cases).

So if we look at

```
new Magister(...).ready(checkLogin(error));
```

and replace `checkLogin` with it's value (the function) it becomes

```
new Magister(...).ready(function checkLogin(error){...}(error));
```

However, that doesn't look like the first version at all! Suddenly a wild `(error)` appears at the end of our function definition.

Lets go the other way round:

```
new Magister(...).ready(function(error){...});
// becomes
new Magister(...).ready(function checkError(error){...});
// becomes
function checkError(error) { ... }
new Magister(...).ready(checkError);
```

Much better.

Comment: Okay, I understand! So `checkLogin(error)` would actually execute the function and return its value to whatever called it, and `checkLogin` refers to the function, to be given arguments by whatever called it?